# Hazelcast doesnt connect to 5704 port

Tags: java, distributed-computing, hazelcast

I started hazelcast server in 4 instances .For each of the instance i gave different group name.Now from the client when i am trying to connect to the 4 instance,its failing. Hazelcast is by default checking only for 5701,5702,5703 and it doesn't even look for 5704.How can i configure hazelcast client to look for all the instances
The below is the log

> com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationException: Invalid credentials!    at
> com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl$2.onResponse(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:525)
> at
> com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl$2.onResponse(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:507)
> at
> com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture$1.run(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:251)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    at
> com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
> at
> com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)
> 12:30:22.570 [hz.client_0.internal-2] WARN
> com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection - hz.client_0
> [PAVAN] [3.7.4] ClientConnection{live=false, connectionId=2,
> socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected
> local=/127.0.0.1:34798 remote=/127.0.0.1:5702]}, remoteEndpoint=null,
> lastReadTime=2017-01-25 12:30:22.569, lastWriteTime=2017-01-25
> 12:30:22.568, closedTime=2017-01-25 12:30:22.569,
> lastHeartbeatRequested=never, lastHeartbeatReceived=never, connected
> server version=null} lost. Reason:
> com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationException[Invalid credentials!]
> 12:30:22.570 [main] WARN
> com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport - hz.client_0
> [PAVAN] [3.7.4] Exception during initial connection to
> localhost/127.0.0.1:5702 com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationException:
> Invalid credentials!  at
> com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl$2.onResponse(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:525)
> at
> com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl$2.onResponse(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:507)
> at
> com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture$1.run(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:251)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    at
> com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
> at
> com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)
> 12:30:22.574 [hz.client_0.internal-2] WARN
> com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection - hz.client_0
> [PAVAN] [3.7.4] ClientConnection{live=false, connectionId=3,
> socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected
> local=/127.0.0.1:58426 remote=/127.0.0.1:5701]}, remoteEndpoint=null,
> lastReadTime=2017-01-25 12:30:22.573, lastWriteTime=2017-01-25
> 12:30:22.571, closedTime=2017-01-25 12:30:22.573,
> lastHeartbeatRequested=never, lastHeartbeatReceived=never, connected
> server version=null} lost. Reason:
> com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationException[Invalid credentials!]
> 12:30:22.574 [main] WARN
> com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport - hz.client_0
> [PAVAN] [3.7.4] Exception during initial connection to
> localhost/127.0.0.1:5701 com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationException:
> Invalid credentials!  at
> com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl$2.onResponse(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:525)
> at
> com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl$2.onResponse(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:507)
> at
> com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture$1.run(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:251)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    at
> com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
> at
> com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)
> 12:30:22.575 [main] WARN
> com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport - hz.client_0
> [PAVAN] [3.7.4] Unable to get alive cluster connection, try in 2955 ms
> later, attempt 1 of 2. 12:30:25.534 [hz.client_0.internal-2] WARN
> com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection - hz.client_0
> [PAVAN] [3.7.4] ClientConnection{live=false, connectionId=4,
> socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected
> local=/127.0.0.1:34802 remote=/127.0.0.1:5702]}, remoteEndpoint=null,
> lastReadTime=2017-01-25 12:30:25.533, lastWriteTime=2017-01-25
> 12:30:25.533, closedTime=2017-01-25 12:30:25.533,
> lastHeartbeatRequested=never, lastHeartbeatReceived=never, connected
> server version=null} lost. Reason:
> com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationException[Invalid credentials!]
> 12:30:25.535 [main] WARN
> com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport - hz.client_0
> [PAVAN] [3.7.4] Exception during initial connection to
> localhost/127.0.0.1:5702 com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationException:
> Invalid credentials!  at
> com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl$2.onResponse(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:525)
> at
> com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl$2.onResponse(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:507)
> at
> com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture$1.run(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:251)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    at
> com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
> at
> com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)
> 12:30:25.538 [hz.client_0.internal-2] WARN
> com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection - hz.client_0
> [PAVAN] [3.7.4] ClientConnection{live=false, connectionId=5,
> socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected
> local=/127.0.0.1:58430 remote=/127.0.0.1:5701]}, remoteEndpoint=null,
> lastReadTime=2017-01-25 12:30:25.537, lastWriteTime=2017-01-25
> 12:30:25.537, closedTime=2017-01-25 12:30:25.537,
> lastHeartbeatRequested=never, lastHeartbeatReceived=never, connected
> server version=null} lost. Reason:
> com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationException[Invalid credentials!]
> 12:30:25.539 [main] WARN
> com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport - hz.client_0
> [PAVAN] [3.7.4] Exception during initial connection to
> localhost/127.0.0.1:5701 com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationException:
> Invalid credentials!  at
> com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl$2.onResponse(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:525)
> at
> com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl$2.onResponse(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:507)
> at
> com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture$1.run(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:251)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    at
> com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
> at
> com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)
> 12:30:25.545 [hz.client_0.internal-2] WARN
> com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnection - hz.client_0
> [PAVAN] [3.7.4] ClientConnection{live=false, connectionId=6,
> socketChannel=DefaultSocketChannelWrapper{socketChannel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected
> local=/127.0.0.1:49389 remote=/127.0.0.1:5703]}, remoteEndpoint=null,
> lastReadTime=2017-01-25 12:30:25.542, lastWriteTime=2017-01-25
> 12:30:25.541, closedTime=2017-01-25 12:30:25.542,
> lastHeartbeatRequested=never, lastHeartbeatReceived=never, connected
> server version=null} lost. Reason:
> com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationException[Invalid credentials!]
> 12:30:25.545 [main] WARN
> com.hazelcast.client.spi.impl.ClusterListenerSupport - hz.client_0
> [PAVAN] [3.7.4] Exception during initial connection to
> localhost/127.0.0.1:5703 com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationException:
> Invalid credentials!  at
> com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl$2.onResponse(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:525)
> at
> com.hazelcast.client.connection.nio.ClientConnectionManagerImpl$2.onResponse(ClientConnectionManagerImpl.java:507)
> at
> com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture$1.run(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:251)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    at
> com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.executeRun(HazelcastManagedThread.java:76)
> at
> com.hazelcast.util.executor.HazelcastManagedThread.run(HazelcastManagedThread.java:92)

```
public class HCServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("hazelcast.tcp.join.port.try.count", "10");
        String hazelcastGroup = args[0];
        Config config = new Config();
        config.getGroupConfig().setName(hazelcastGroup).setPassword(hazelcastGroup);
        Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
    }
}



public class HcClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("hazelcast.tcp.join.port.try.count", "10");
        String hazelcastGroup = args[0];
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.getGroupConfig().setName(hazelcastGroup).setPassword(hazelcastGroup);
        HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is your exact question as your exception doesn't seem to be connected to what I read as your question. Anyhow the exception is about invalid credentials (`com.hazelcast.client.AuthenticationException: Invalid credentials`) which means your client has different groupname / password configuration than the node it wants to connect to.

On the other hand I'm not sure what you mean by "4 nodes, all different groupname", what's the idea behind that? If you want a 4 node cluster, they should all have the same groupname and password and so should the client. If you want 4 independent clusters you need to create 4 Hazelcast clients with their own unique configuration each (each one matching one cluster's group config).

Connecting to port above 5703, you need to configure the address specifically by adding it to the addresses to connect to, in common format ip:port.

Overall I see multiple things that seems to be wrong and I'm not sure what you try to do right now but I hope it still helps.

Comment: My question is like this i started 4 HC servers with groupname A,B,C,D and each started in different ports like 5701,5702,5703,5704 respectively.Now am trying to connect my client by specifying the groupname as D.But HC is searching for only 5701,5702,5703.Its not seraching for 5704 port.Its not a cluster

Comment: My question is how to make Hazelcast search for ports beyond 5703 port?By default its only searching for 5701,5702,5703.But i have instance started on 5704.

Comment: It doesn't. Either you define a host as "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5704" or you wait until the 5704 node figures out the other ones (which most probably only works on localhost).

Comment: But hazelcast.tcp.join.port.try.count specifies it is possible in hazelcast documentation http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/systemproperties.html

Comment: And its not a cluster for 5704 to find the other ports.Can you please help me out.If this is possible in Hazelcast

Comment: Yes you can set `hazelcast.tcp.join.port.try.count` in the configfile or as a cmdline property. It'll solve your issue but you shouldn't have that issue anyways. There is no meaningful reason to have multiple nodes in production on the same system, therefore there is no reason to have this property set to anything :-)

Comment: This is for our test environment and even setting hazelcast.tcp.join.port.try.count didn't solve my problem

Comment: Where did you set this property? If it doesn't work, please file an issue on github with, if possible, some small program to reproduce / demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I have edited my post by adding programs to reproduce this :)